# Difference between "interwoven" and "complected"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *interwoven* and *complected*?

> [complect](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/complect)
>   To join by weaving or twining together; interweave.

Comment: I assume you mean complicated. Complected is something altogether different.

Comment: @richardb Thanks for the note, I've checked again. Some sources (e.g. Marriam-Webster) do not list them as synonyms/related. I added a source that does. It seems that's half the answer already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stand corrected. In that case, I would say that complected is such an obscure word that most native speakers would not understand it.

[Google Ngram link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=complected%2C%20interwoven&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomplected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterwoven%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccomplected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterwoven%3B%2Cc0)